# AWSSDK.S3 NuGet package not supported under DNX Core 5.0

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, asp.net-core-1.0

I've added the AWSSDK.S3 package to my ASP.NET 5.0/Core 1.0 project and I'm getting an error when compiling:

> Error NU1002  The dependency PCLCrypto 1.0.2.15130 in project [my project] does not support framework DNXCore,Version=v5.0.   [my project]
>
> Error NU1002  The dependency Validation 2.0.6.15003 in project [my project] does not support framework DNXCore,Version=v5.0.  [my project]

Is there any work-around I can use that might allow me to compile and use the S3 libraries? I'm in the process of pulling apart the NuGet files, but I'm not sure if this will work.